# PostgreSQL CREATE INDEX memory requirement

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.3, memory

I've got 6GB of RAM on my laptop and for a test I'm creating a 50mil-rows table in PostgreSQL 9.3.  I then want to create an index on the table.

The table and the resulting index together (or twice the table total size) can fit into 5GB of RAM and I set `maintenance_work_mem` to 5GB, still `CREATE INDEX` uses external sort with about 1.4GB of temp files.  Why is that so?

Is my expectation that it should be able to sort in RAM unreasonable?

```
test=# set maintenance_work_mem to '5GB';
SET
test=# create table t1 as (select i::int, random() as f from generate_series(1, 50000000) i);
SELECT 50000000
test=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('t1'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 2111 MB
(1 row)

test=# create index on t1(f, i);
CREATE INDEX
test=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('t1_f_i_idx'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 1504 MB
(1 row)
```

In the server log:

```
LOG:  temporary file: path "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp22623.1", size 1073741824
STATEMENT:  create index on t1(f, i);
LOG:  temporary file: path "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp22623.2", size 327622656
LOG:  external sort ended, 171065 disk blocks used: CPU 6.78s/268.73u sec elapsed 313.18 sec
```

Is there a way to calculate `CREATE INDEX` memory requirement before actually running it?

Comment: What is your `work_mem` option set to?  It's not the same thing as `maintenance_work_mem` .. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-resource.html

Comment: My `work_mem` is default (1MB), but `CREATE INDEX` doesn't depend on it.

Comment: Ah - I see on the `CREATE INDEX` doc page now as well as the link I pasted. Sorry for the misdirection.

Comment: See my comment to the accepted answer.  One other thing to consider is that using an --enable-cassert build (which I did) adds memory overhead on every palloc'd chunk (the sizeof(Size): usually 8, or 4 on x86 builds).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Through version 9.3, the indirection array used for sorting had to fit in a single 1GB memory allocation.  This created an artificial limit on the number of tuples which could be sorted in memory.  Once that limit was reached, it had to switch to a disk sort, even if there was memory left over.

This restriction was removed in version 9.4.

Comment: keep in mind that more memory does not always make things faster in terms of sorting. we at cybertec have recently run a test indicating that an infinite amount of maintenance_work_mem does not necessarily speed things up - however, it depends a bit on the disk system as well.

Comment: Indeed, this was the root cause.  There is 50x10^6 tuples to sort and the indirection array uses 24 bytes per tuple, hence it needs 1200x10^6 bytes.  The relevant commit is this: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/263865a48973767ce8ed7b7788059a38a24a9f37#diff-3f5bac8914c4fcb080d72931f938f8a6R1053